# Java locking structure best pattern

Tags: java, multithreading

What is the difference from technical perspective between those two listings? First is one that is provided in java doc of [lock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html). Second is mine.

1.

```
 Lock l = ...;
         l.lock();
         try {
             // access the resource protected by this lock
         } finally {
             l.unlock();
         }
```

2.

```
Lock l = ...;

     try {
         l.lock();
         // access the resource protected by this lock
     } finally {
         l.unlock();
     }
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The reason is to be found in [the javadoc of the `.unlock()` documentation of `Lock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html#unlock--):

> Implementation Considerations
>
> A Lock implementation will usually impose restrictions on which thread can release a lock (typically only the holder of the lock can release it) **and may throw an (unchecked) exception if the restriction is violated**. Any restrictions and the exception type must be documented by that Lock implementation.

Similarly, a `.lock()` may fail with an unchecked exception.

Which means that in:

```
l.lock();
try {
    ...
} finally {
    l.unlock();
}
```

if the *locking* fails, you never get to `unlock()`. Whereas in:

```
try {
    l.lock();
    ...
} finally {
    lock.unlock();
}
```

you needlessly throw two exceptions if the locking fails; and one of them will be lost.

Not to mention that depending on the *implementation* of the lock, with the second version you may end up unlocking "someone else"'s lock... Not a good thing.

Comment: so if a lock throws an exception on a lock operation it can be left in a locked state?

Comment: @assylias that is indeed another reason, yes; however, from what I understand of it, nothing guarantees that locks and unlocks are done by the same thread; if anything it makes the first version much safer to use. Well, maybe I have misread the documentation -- again

Comment: To clarify, only the `lock`ing thread can `unlock`.  Assylias' comment would result in an `IllegalMonitorStateException`.

Answer (score 5):

The difference is in what happens if `l` is null:

- The first example will fail with an exception that points to the first line, above the try block.
- The second example will fail with an NPE that gets masked by another NPE thrown from the finally block.

Also if locking fails, the finally block in the second example could attempt to unlock a lock that was not locked, where the first example will not.

Comment: That is far from being the only possible reason... And if `l` is null you have another problem to begin with!

Comment: See the JavaDoc on `lock()` allows implementations to throw unchecked exceptions if they detect erroneous use. An example might be a non-reentrant lock that fails if misused.

Comment: @Ben: but it doesn't say it locks in a closed state. and the usage in the java.util.concurrent code doesn't seem to be concerned about that.